# Why is my IList<T> being returned as a list of null objects?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Whilst I realise that a Set or Bag is probably the correct way to do this, I'm new to NHibernate and I'm trying to understand why the following is happening.

I have two classes:

```
public class Customer
{
  public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
  public virtual string CustomerName { get; set; }
  // Customer has many domains
  public virtual IList<Domain> Domains { get; set; }
}

public class Domain
{
  public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
  public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
  public virtual string DomainName { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping files look like:

```
<!-- Domain -> tblDomains           -->           
<class name="Domain" table="tblDomains">

  <id name="Id">
    <column name="DomainID" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
    <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>

  <property name="CustomerID"/>
  <property name="DomainName"/>

</class>

<!-- Customer -> tblCustomer       -->
<class name="Customer" table="tblCustomer">

  <id name="Id">
    <column name="CustomerID" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
    <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>

  <property name="CustomerName" column="Customer"/>

  <list name="Domains">
    <key column="CustomerID"/>
    <index column="DomainID"/>
    <one-to-many class="Domain" />
  </list>

</class>
```

When I retrieve a `Customer` object the `Domains` property contains a list of 665383 null `Domain` objects. The 665384'th item in the list contains a valid populated object.

There are only 63 `Domain`'s that belong to this customer so I'm guessing this is some kind of cartesian product result. I've peeked at the SQL in NHProfiler but all I see is a query that looks fairly innocent when I iterate over the first item in the `Domains` list:

```
SELECT domains0_.CustomerID  as CustomerID1_,
       domains0_.DomainID    as DomainID1_,
       domains0_.DomainID    as DomainID2_0_,
       domains0_.CustomerID  as CustomerID2_0_,
       domains0_.DomainName  as DomainName2_0_
FROM   tblDomains domains0_
WHERE  domains0_.CustomerID = 5667 /* @p0 */
```

If I use a `<bag>` this all works just fine. Can anyone explain what's going on under the bonnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a list mapping, the index applies to the set of objects in the list. That is, if a Customer has a set of 63 Domains then normally the list would contain values from 0 to 62 to indicate the index of the Domain object in that Customer's set of Domains.

You have set the index to DomainId, the primary key of the table, which is wreaking havoc. I would guess that the Domain table has 665384 rows total (or fewer if DomainId doesn't start with 1 and has gaps), but I would think that 63 would be valid instead of one. Did you check them all? :-)

Comment: So `<index>` should only ever be used where there is a column that has a contiguous range (say 0 -> 10) per `CustomerID` with no gaps? Just for FYI, the domain table has 53973 rows.

Comment: Ok...I eventually found *For lists, this column contains sequential integers numbered from zero. Make sure that your index really starts from zero if you have to deal with legacy data.* in the docos.